# Using interface declarations in separate file

Tags: ios, interface

game.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  UIImageView * player;
}

@end
```

game.m

```
-(void)InitPlayer
{    
  player.tag = 0;
}
```

player.m

I want InitPlayer in this file instead but keep declaration in game.h file.

```
- (void)InitPlayer
{
  player.tag = 0;  // access UIImageView *player;

}
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the declaration already in the .h file?

Comment: I get error message "Use of undeclared identifier" when I try to use in second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this to declare `-InitPlayer` part of your class' public interface:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
@private
  UIImageView * player;
}

- (void)InitPlayer;

@end
```

then you keep your implementation of `-InitPlayer` in ViewController.m, where it must reside. You cannot place the method's implementation inside an `@interface` block.

if you are coming from other languages, then you should know that dispatch in objc is dynamic -- placing a definition in the header (if it were possible) would not result in an inlined/optimization.

**In response to the clarified question:**

Ok, then just do this:

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject
- (void)prepareUIImageView:(UIImageView *)pImageView; // << could actually be a class method in this case
@end
```

Player.m

```
@implementation Player

- (void)prepareUIImageView:(UIImageView *)pImageView
{
    pImageView.tag = 0;
}

@end
```

then you can tell the Player to initialize the view from the `ViewController`, assuming it has no controller itself.

(note: objc methods names typically begin with a lowercase character. as well, it's usually a good idea to hide this initialization stuff from your clients)

Comment: @user1434087 expanded and will post another update in a minute…

Comment: Thanks!  This is clear now and I'll change my code to reflect this.